# SwiftUI iPhone: navigating between scenes

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, scene

I am trying to navigate to another scene in SwiftUI because I have an application that can open documents, but also do other things.

I want to have a `WindowGroup` as standard scene and when the user clicks on a button, it should navigate to a `DocumentGroup`.

Or it should open the DocumentGroup as a sheet.

I just have no idea how I can do this. I know it is possible to open a new Scene on iPad and Mac, but this is not possible on iPhone.
I have tried many ways to change the the scene inside of the App's body, with no succes.

Does anyone know how I can navigate between 2 scenes?

Comment: It isn't available in iOS only iPadOS https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/multitasking/